# I am trying to write unit testing of QuerydslRepositorySupport in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, junit5

I am developing a spring boot 2.2.0 application using QuerydslRepositorySupport as a Data Access Object (DAO aka Repository).  I would very much like to write a unit test for it but haven't been successful so far. Has anyone come across this problem before and how do you solve it?  below is my code

BankAccountRepository.java

```
@Repository
public class BankAccountRepository extends QuerydslRepositorySupport {

    private QBankAccountDO qBankAccount = QBankAccountDO.bankAccountDO;

    public BankAccountRepository() {
        super(BankAccountDO.class);
    }

    public Page<BankAccountDO> searchBankAccountDOByShopId(SearchBankAccountRequest request, Pageable pageable) {
        if(request == null || request.getShopId() == null) {
            return new PageImpl<>(new ArrayList<BankAccountDO>(), pageable, 0L);
        }

        JPQLQuery<BankAccountDO> query = from(qBankAccount).where( qBankAccount.shop.id.eq(request.getShopId()) );

        return new PageImpl<>(getQuerydsl().applyPagination(pageable, query).fetch(), pageable, query.fetchCount());
    }
}
```

BankAccountRepositoryTest.java

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class BankAccountRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private BankAccountRepository bankAccountRepository;

    @Test
    public void testtest() {
        assertThat(bankAccountRepository).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

src/test/resources/application.properties

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.liquibase.enabled=true
spring.liquibase.contexts=development
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:liquibase/liquibase.xml
spring.liquibase.drop-first=false
```

test result

```
2019-11-01 20:35:07.235  INFO 6964 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
2019-11-01 20:35:07.438  INFO 6964 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2019-11-01 20:35:07.594  INFO 6964 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.6.Final}
2019-11-01 20:35:07.828  INFO 6964 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2019-11-01 20:35:08.000  INFO 6964 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-11-01 20:35:08.889  INFO 6964 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.smehelper.product.entity.SubProductDO (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2019-11-01 20:35:09.249  INFO 6964 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2019-11-01 20:35:09.264  INFO 6964 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'



============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceConfiguration matched:
      - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.PooledDataSourceAvailable PooledDataSource found supported DataSource; NestedCondition on DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition.ExplicitType @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'type' (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.PooledDataSourceCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,javax.sql.XADataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.HikariPoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate', 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean', 'javax.persistence.EntityManager', 'org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor' (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.sql.DataSource', 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'dataSource' (OnBeanCondition)

   JdbcTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactory matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#jpaVendorAdapter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration#transactionManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource'; @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean,org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase', 'liquibase.change.DatabaseChange' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.liquibase.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - AnyNestedCondition 1 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseDataSourceCondition.LiquibaseUrlCondition @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.liquibase.url) did not find property 'url'; NestedCondition on LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseDataSourceCondition.DataSourceBeanCondition @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'dataSource' (LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseDataSourceCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseEntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean; SearchStrategy: all) found bean '&entityManagerFactory' (OnBeanCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseJdbcOperationsDependsOnPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'jdbcTemplate' (OnBeanCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.LiquibaseNamedParameterJdbcOperationsDependsOnPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'namedParameterJdbcTemplate' (OnBeanCondition)

   NamedParameterJdbcTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'jdbcTemplate'; @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)

   TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration#embeddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.test.database.replace=ANY) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration#testEntityManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration#platformTransactionManagerCustomizers matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionManagerCustomizers; SearchStrategy: all) did2019-11-01 20:35:10.294  INFO 6964 --- [           main] c.s.s.r.BankAccountRepositoryTest        : Started BankAccountRepositoryTest in 13.123 seconds (JVM running for 16.445)
 not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'transactionManager'; @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found a primary bean from beans 'transactionManager' (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.TransactionTemplateConfiguration#transactionTemplate matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionOperations; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   CacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerEntityManagerFactoryDependsOnPostProcessor:
      Did not match:
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)

   CaffeineCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine', 'org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CouchbaseCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket', 'com.couchbase.client.spring.cache.CouchbaseCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - EmbeddedDataSource found supported pooled data source (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Dbcp2:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Generic:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.type) did not find property 'spring.datasource.type' (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourceConfiguration.Tomcat:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceJmxConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jmx.enabled=true) found different value in property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.CommonsDbcp2PoolDataSourceMetadataProviderConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourcePoolMetadataProvidersConfiguration.TomcatDataSourcePoolMetadataProviderConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource' (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration#transactionManager:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' transactionManager (OnBeanCondition)

   EhCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'net.sf.ehcache.Cache', 'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   FlywayAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.flywaydb.core.Flyway' (OnClassCondition)

   GenericCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration unknown cache type (CacheCondition)

   HazelcastCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance', 'com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   InfinispanCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.infinispan.spring.embedded.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.cache.Caching', 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JpaBaseConfiguration.JpaWebConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - not a servlet web application (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration#entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer:
      Did not match:
         - AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition.LazyBootstrapMode @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=lazy) did not find property 'bootstrap-mode'; NestedCondition on JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition.DeferredBootstrapMode @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=deferred) did not find property 'bootstrap-mode' (JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.BootstrapExecutorCondition)

   RedisCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   SimpleCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration unknown cache type (CacheCondition)

   TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration#dataSource:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.test.database.replace=AUTO_CONFIGURED) did not find property 'replace' (OnPropertyCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration#transactionalOperator:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.transaction.ReactiveTransactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration.EnableTransactionManagementConfiguration.JdkDynamicAutoProxyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false) did not find property 'proxy-target-class' (OnPropertyCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration



2019-11-01 20:35:10.341 ERROR 6964 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@68e5eea7] to prepare test instance [com.smehelper.shop.repository.BankAccountRepositoryTest@6497b078]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.smehelper.shop.repository.BankAccountRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bankAccountRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.smehelper.shop.repository.BankAccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:393) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) [spring-test-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$285/195381554.execute(Unknown Source) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$284/298430307.accept(Unknown Source) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator$$Lambda$89/1413653265.accept(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor$$Lambda$278/896644936.get(Unknown Source) [junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249) [na:1.8.0_40]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$174/1166151249.execute(Unknown Source) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$173/1897115967.invoke(Unknown Source) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask$$Lambda$172/2095490653.execute(Unknown Source) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) [junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) [.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) [.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher$$Lambda$141/120694604.accept(Unknown Source) [.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) [.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) [.cp/:na]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) [.cp/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

write in Application.properties file
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR